# How can I hide my IP without using a proxy?

Tags: ssh, ip-address, hamachi

I've been trying to do this for some time.  I have installed Hamachi and used in correlation with privoxy.  This is all well and good except I'd like to accomplish this without the use of a proxy service since it dramatically slows my connection and is not very secure.  I only have one computer in my network.  Is it possible to hide my ip with SSH in Win7 or somehow make my Hamachi address the one websites will see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Privoxy seems to be more of a firewall or content filtering service. You are looking for an [onion router](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion_routing).  An onion router will act as your proxy and should not release your ip address unless the system is somehow compromised.

You do need a proxy service because the Internet Protocol needs to know where to send the traffic: your IP address.  If you use a proxy, the proxy will act as your agent and send you the traffic it receives on your behalf.  But the proxy must know where to send it to, so the proxy will need to know your ip address.  [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) is one of the more popular proxy services people use for privacy (I'm told - never used it myself).  You can get better throughput if you pay for a proxy instead of using a free one.

Comment: Thanks, I actually stumbled upon Tor before I read your answer.  I'm currently using Tor configured with Privoxy as well as  Hamachi.  It's probably not the best way to browse anonymously however possibly the best "free" way.  Loads of thanks for everyone's replies, extremely useful stuff. Cheers!

Comment: Dissidents and rebels in countries like Iran and China rely on Tor to protect their identity, so please be mindful of how you consume Tor's resources.  Onion routers do require significant processing when traffic volume is high.  If you are using Tor for entertainment to transfer large amounts of data, I recommend you use a pay service to keep resources on the free service open for dissidents and such.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the protocol, you may be able to modify a string or similar to change the IP, however, this is highly unlikely it will work everywhere and if there is any sort of firewall/monitoring software used at the target, they will most likely be able to see the originating IP anyway.

You are basically saying, I want to connect to a target. Connecting will always say where you are as a target needs a way to pass the information back to you - originating information is part of a data packet. The only way to connect and to pass a different address is to connect from a different place and this is a proxy.

If your connection was very slow, perhaps consider using a VPN/Proxy from somewhere with a faster upload speed.

Comment: I believe forms of this *used* to be possible in the early days of the internet, but the routers stopped allowing oddball traffic because as you stated, it doesn't make much sense and is often malicious. I need to dig up a citation on that, but it'd be mostly of historical interest.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I know packet injecting/fiddling still works - it is one of the main instruments for wifi hacking.. but, I think you are correct as for over the internet - even if you had a router that allowed it, your ISP's own router/security would probably block it somewhere/somehow. Personally, I can't think of any reason to do this other than for malicious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

A proxy is necessary because you let the proxy know your real IP, and the proxy fetches pages on your behalf.

If the Internet doesn't know your IP, how can they send you any data?

Comment: And hope the proxy isn't using x-forwarded-for type headers...